# How to adjust rectangular images to show up as a square in an instagram-like grid of images without losing page responsiveness

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, responsiveness

If you guys [take a look at the code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VoZEZa/), when I add squared images (first row), the grid will fit perfectly just like instagram. I want to make different shaped images fits in this same squared width and height when I add them (second row).

The problem is, if I just try to make it a square by changing the width and height of the `.column > img` selector from `100%` to `300px` for example, the images won't resize in page responsiveness and everything becomes a mess of images overlaying each other.

```css
body {
    font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 930px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.column {
    width: 33.33%;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 28px;
}

.column>img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 760px) {
    .row {
        margin-bottom: 3px;
    }

    .column {
        margin-right: 3px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
    .row {
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .column {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 6px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

   <div class="row">
       <div class="column">
           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498471731312-b6d2b8280c61?w=500&h=500&fit=crop">
       </div>
       <div class="column">
           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1515023115689-589c33041d3c?w=500&h=500&fit=crop">
       </div>
       <div class="column">
           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502630859934-b3b41d18206c?w=500&h=500&fit=crop">
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
       <div class="column">
           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523354177913-be035fcee55e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80">
       </div>
       <div class="column">
           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563281746-48bb478e9b2a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=80">
       </div>
       <div class="column">
           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563170446-9c3c0622d8a9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1534&q=80">
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make all images a square and at the same time keep the responsiveness of the width and height when resizing the page? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a solution. In my solution I've used `object-fit` property to resize image. Check it. Hope it will be helpful to you.

```css
body {
    font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 930px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.column {
    width: 33.33vw; /*These properties are changed*/
    height: 33.33vw; /*These properties are changed*/
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 28px;
}

.column>img {
    width: 33.33vw; /*These properties are changed*/
    height: 33.33vw; /*These properties are changed*/
    object-fit: cover; /*These properties are changed*/
}

@media (max-width: 760px) {
    .row {
        margin-bottom: 3px;
    }

    .column {
        margin-right: 3px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
    .row {
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .column {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 6px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

   <div class="row">
       <div class="column">
           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498471731312-b6d2b8280c61?w=500&h=500&fit=crop">
       </div>
       <div class="column">
           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1515023115689-589c33041d3c?w=500&h=500&fit=crop">
       </div>
       <div class="column">
           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502630859934-b3b41d18206c?w=500&h=500&fit=crop">
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
       <div class="column">
           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523354177913-be035fcee55e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80">
       </div>
       <div class="column">
           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563281746-48bb478e9b2a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=80">
       </div>
       <div class="column">
           <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563170446-9c3c0622d8a9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1534&q=80">
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `object-fit` ist not supported by Internet Explorer (all versions), some mobile browsers and only partially by Edge. But all in all, I think not supportin IE is a feature.

Comment: Hahahaha I have to agree about the IE support. Thank you very much for the solution. Simple and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You can abuse padding for this.

tl;dr: https://jsfiddle.net/Hoargarth/u247vz0k/ Just look at the fiddle, pretty self explanatory

---

First of all we are using flexboxes, for this we need a flex container and flex items in it.

```
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://www.url.to/image.png');">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- Any number of flex items inside container -->

</div>
```

I'm not explayning the flex-system here, I guess you should know about it.
But for everyone not knowing about flex, here is a pretty good explanation: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

So we start at the `flex-item`:

`position: relative` because we need the next element
(`image-wrapper`) to be absolute positioned to flex-item

`width: 32%`
becasue you want 3 images per row, don't forget to give your
flex-container a width

`padding-bottom: 32%` the padding is the key, 32% padding is relative to the width of the flex-container. So if you use `padding-bottom: 100%`, the flex-item's height would be exact same like flex-container width. In our case we want a quadratic image, so we use `32%`

```
.flex-item {
    position: relative;
    width: 32%;
    padding-bottom: 32%;
}
```

---

Next is `image-wrapper`:

`position: absolute` because we don't wanna take this container (or any other container inside this one) to take up any more space.

`overflow: hidden` to make sure nothing can escape our quadratic image and overlaps to another container

```
.image-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

---

And last, the `image` itself:

No magic here, just add your background image as `background-image: url()` in html so you don't have to create a lot of extra classes.

`position: relative` I don't remember why I added it, maybe some crossbrowser related stuff. But you can try to remove it, it's working on Firefox without.

`background` `*-size: cover` so all the quadratic space gets filled, no matter what size the image is; `*-position: 50%` to completely center the image (vertically and horizontally); `*-repeat: no-repeat` you don't really need it since `background-size: cover` fills the whole space, I just added it so there is no special case where the image would be repeated

```
.image {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

---

This solution is responsive out of the box, but you can change the number of Images per Row with simple Media Queries:
Example:

```
/*Window Width smaller 800px with two images per row*/
.flex-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 48%;
  padding-bottom: 48%;
}

/*Window Width larger or equal 800px with three images per row*/
@media (min-width: 800px){
    .flex-item {
    width: 32%;
    padding-bottom: 32%;
  }
}
```

---

I hope it's understandable, if not let me know!

Comment: That's cool, didn't even know it was a thing placing images with div's. And that css-tricks article is great! Thank you so much for the knowledge, your efforts are very appreciated.